# Could someone explain the time complexity for these code snippets?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am practicing time complexity and some of them if a bit too complicated for me.
I would really appreciate of someone could explain these for me.

A) The time complexity is O(n). How is that?

```
for (int i = N; i > 0; i = i/2) {
    for (int j = i+i; j > 0; j--) {
         doSomething(i, j);
    }
}
```

B) The time complexity is O(n logn). How is that?

```
for (int i = N+N; i > 0; i--) {
    for (int j = N; j > 0; j = j/2) {
        doSomething(i, j);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find time complexity of an algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm)

Comment: I have been practicing time complexity with many different examples. This is a very good link but I still had a hard time getting my head around these two algorithms. But thank you anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose we must assume that the execution of `doSomething` takes constant time, independent of the values it gets as arguments.

#### Algorithm A:

On the first iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop iterates 2 times. Every next iteration of the outer loop, the number of iterations of the inner loop is halved. So we get this series:

2 +  + /2 + /4 + /8 + ... + 2

Given that this series is finite, but has the pattern of [1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + ...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/2_%2B_1/4_%2B_1/8_%2B_1/16_%2B_%E2%8B%AF), we can conclude that this is less than 4, and so it is O().

#### Algorithm B:

Here the number of iterations of the inner loop does not depend on the value of , so it is always the same: each time it performs  log<sub><sub>2</sub></sub> iterations (since  is halved each iteration). As the outer loop iterates 2 times, `doSomething` is called 2log<sub><sub>2</sub></sub>, which is O(log)

Answer (score -1):

**problem A**

Here the first loop will execute *log2(n)+1* times, and the second loop will execute *i+i* times. So what will the value of *i* in every second loop.

for n, it will be like

*n + n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + n/16 + .......*

summation of this will be the answer.

as we know
*a + ar + ar^2 + ar^3 + ar^4 .... + ar^m = (1-a^(m+1))/(1-a*)

here a = n, r = 1/2 and m = log2(n)+1

n + n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + ... n/(2^(m)) =2n−n/2^m =  2n-1;

so the complexity is *O(2n-1) = O(n)*

**problem B**

here the first loop will execute n times. And for every first loop execution, the second loop will be executed *log2(n)+1* time.

for (int j = n; j > 0; j = j/2)

for example n = 10 ,
value of j will be 10, 5, 2, 1 ,0. For 10 it will execute 4 times or log2(10)+1 times .

so for every first loop it will execute log2(n)+1 times. so the complexity is
*O(n(log2(n)+1)) = O (nlog(n))*